# what does this part imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> The poetry festivals of the pre-Islamic period often pitched two poets against each other in a war of verse in which one would be deemed winner by the audience. Literary criticism also grew into theology, and thus gained a more official status with Islamic study of the Qur'an. **Although nothing which might be termed 'literary criticism', in the modern sense, was applied to a work held to be i'jaz or inimitable and divinely inspired, analysis was permitted.** This study allowed for better understanding of the message and facilitated interpretation for practical use, all of which help the development of a critical method important for later work on other literature.

I am wondering what the bold part could mean.

Could anyone please in a more readily way explain it?

Any comment would be appreciated

Comment: I certainly hope that poets were not _pitched_ against each other.  Is that actually what the original says?  I think it wants to be _pitted_.  But, hey.  Go far enough back in the Christian West and there was a single umbrella term (jongleur) which encompassed both singers and acrobat-tumblers.  It could have totally happened.

Comment: @Codeswitcher I've read lots of poems that have led me to conclude that the poet should be pitched somewhere. Perhaps out a window.

Comment: @jay Ha! Touché.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern literary criticism dares to pronounce judgment on whether a work is well done in its various aspects.  To subject a work of poetry which was believed to be literally the work of Allah to such critical review does seem... impertinent.  I have this vision of some rascally medieval critic writing, "The Sovereign Lord has chosen some promising themes, but fails to really elaborate on them satisfactorily; more disappointing, the All Compassionate has a weak sense of rhythmic structure...."  No, not likely to be well received.

But analysis, that is exploration of the *meaning* of a divinely inspired work is fine; in fact, can be an act of adoration and devotion.